# Can you exclude a timeframe in a Jenkins build schedule?

Tags: jenkins

I currently have a Jenkins job that is scheduled to run every 30 mins every day. It is configured as this: H/30 * * * *

I'd like to also tell the scheduler to run every 30 mins except from 2-3am. Is this possible? I can't seem to find exclusions in the schedule documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured this one out after all.

H/30 0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * *

You need to explicitly set the hours by which you want the job to run, so in the csv list add all hours, except for 2 to keep tests from running between 2am and 2:59am

Comment: A range of of hours doesn't ensure the test runs for each hour in the range though, right? If you wanted it to include every hour wouldn't you need to explicitly list the hours you wanted?

Comment: The hours field is a list of hours you want to run the job.  `*` means all hours.  A range means each hour within the range (inclusive).  A comma-delimited list means each hour in the list.  `*` is equivalent to `0-23`.

Comment: @Dave probably could be simplified to `H/30 0-1,3-23 * * *`